# COMException (8004014) using ShockwaveFlashObjects in VS2008 on Vista x64

Tags: flash, com

I'm trying to embed a Flash object in my app.  I've added a reference to the ShockwaveFlash COM Object but the app fails at instantiation:

```
ShockwaveFlashObjects.ShockwaveFlashClass shockwave = new ShockwaveFlashObjects.ShockwaveFlashClass();
```

With the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

I'm running Vista x64, could that be the problem?

Anyone experience this before?  Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

80040154 is REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. Most likely, your code runs in a 64 bit process but Shockwave is only installed for 32 bit.

Comment: You know I thought I setting the Platform Target to x86, but I guess I didn't try that.  Sure enough, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

But when I changed Target CPU from 'Any' to 'x86', it worked.